# Plugin needed to allow subscribers to post articles on the front end without admin approval

Tags: custom-post-types, users, front-end

Folks,

I'm working on a magazine that has two areas: a professional writer driven portion and a user submitted portion.  We want the user submitted portion to be able to be formatted like the professional articles (including embedding videos and either uploading or easily linking to photos), but we don't want to give folks back end access for security purposes.  We had tested out UCan Post, but it has a lot of security issues and after we added Bulletproof Security, it's upload feature ceased to work altogether.  We tried out Post from Site, but it's extremely limited and buggy when it comes to categories.

Essentially, the main thing we want to find is a plugin that will allow base level subscribers to post articles from the front end (without waiting on admin approval) and include: 
An easy way to upload pictures or embed photos/videos from sites like YouTube or Flickr
Categorization
Basic Formatting
Support of custom post types

To see what we've got so far, go to: http://www.darkestgoth.com/wp/communitygoth/submit/

Thanks,

Jeremy

Comment: Plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) now.

Answer (score 1):

I had been using TDO mini forms (free) plugin for quite some time, and it worked reasonably well, for our 12000 members. It has some limitations/bugs, and I think it is no longer really supported. Now I have switched to using Gravity Forms, (not free), it is perfect for subscribers to post from the frontend, and even has payment options, (which we use to charge users/subscribers for posting to certain categories), though it is quite expensive with the Paypal addon.

Joe

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Answers. Thanks for posting an answer. Just FYI, you'll notice the question is closed in case you don't see any activity on your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin
[Post From Site](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-from-site/)